# How to resolve "ANCESTOR OUTDATED" issue on Gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

My patch on Gerrit needs to be merged, but there is an error of "ANCESTOR OUTDATED". This is because the commit that my patch depends on has been outdated/abandoned, and replaced with a new merged commit.

I thought that I could simply do `git rebase -i HEAD~2` and edit the dependency. By editing the dependency, I mean that once I rebased onto the dependency commit (1 commit behind HEAD), I could cherrypick the new changes there.

However, I get a long error message:

```
interactive rebase in progress; onto SHA#
Last command done (1 command done):
   edit *** DEPENDENCY
Next command to do (1 remaining command):
   pick *** MY PATCH
You are currently rebasing branch 'temp' on 'SHA#'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

Otherwise, please use 'git reset'
```

How can I simply update the commit that is right behind my HEAD and then solve this ANCESTOR OUTDATED issue on Gerrit?

Edit: The reason why I can't do this rebasing quickly with Gerrit's "Rebase Change" button is because it says that there are merge conflicts and it cannot due it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution (must be done in the working directory of your project):

1. git fetch ssh://repo_of_project official_branch
2. git checkout -b my_branch FETCH_HEAD
3. cherry-pick your latest patch from Gerrit: git fetch ssh://repo_of_project refs/changes/xx/SHA_ID/xx && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
4. Resolve any merge conflicts
5. git add
6. git commit --amend
7. git push ...

--> This pretty much fixes your branches outdated commit history and puts your patch correctly at the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you:

- **checkout** to you desired ancestral,
- **cherry-pick** your change,
- test you change/solve any merge conflict (if any)
- **commit-ammend***
- finally, **push**

*I'm considering you commit has a gerrit's *[Change-Id](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-changeid.html)*; if doesn't, you should do a regular commit to create it (the commit-msg hook is responsible by that).

Also, when I say push, I'm referring to gerrit's approach (which is a `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master` not simply `git push`).